# What are valid attribute names in git? (What is the syntax of git attribute names?)

Tags: git

A quick story what happended: I've been placing in my `.gitattributes` the following:

```
.htaccess merge = ours
```

Then Git was showing an error about "not a valid attribute name".

What I have tried then:

```
.htaccess merge=ours
```

Or to write that out: If you've setting an attribute value, but you’ve put spaces around the equals sign, then just remove the spaces. It's not only me.

*(cf. [STEGRIFF BLOG "GITATTRIBUTES ERROR ‘ IS NOT A VALID ATTRIBUTE NAME’" Written 2015-09-29](https://stegriff.co.uk/upblog/gitattributes-error-is-not-a-valid-attribute-name/))*

But now, apart from that they do not can contain spaces, what are valid attribute names in Git since that date back at then end 2015?

The error message was not telling me for today and my text-generation skills are weak so I could not probe whole Unicode (and the undocumented encodings Git may support) against my local git version and then I don't know which other git versions everyone else is going to use that will checkout the repository.

So back until 2015 looks pretty OK-ish for an answer to me 2023. As this is a question about git, I'd guess there is a grep query that can tell me that, but, uhmm, I feel weak today. Any help much appreceated.

Comment: It would be great to not see any answers that "prompt", but I'm supporting the moderators strike, so no close votes from my end. Please don't read this as an invitation to spam with AI generated answers. Thanks. (but if you add an AI generated answer, please make that directly visible, I'd then much like to read your commentary about the generated answer directly in the answer as well if you're OK to share)

Comment: kindly edit your question. Well you need to explain with question properly so that you can get proper help. Take it or Leave it!

Answer (score 2):

The `gitattributes(5)` documentation says this about the format of each line:

> That is, a pattern followed by an attributes list, separated by whitespaces. Leading and trailing whitespaces are ignored. Lines that begin with # are ignored. Patterns that begin with a double quote are quoted in C style.

The documentation doesn't describe attribute names, but the code does (function `attr_name_valid` in `attr.c`), with this text:

> Attribute name cannot begin with `-` and must consist of characters from `[-A-Za-z0-9_.]`.

The body of the attribute, if any, doesn't seem to be restricted, but I'd strongly encourage you to stick to UTF-8.  Nobody will be happy to have arbitrary byte sequences in the file.

Note that because you specified spaces around the attribute, you tried to define three separate attributes: `merge`, `=`, and `ours`.  Since `=` is not a valid attribute, you got that error message.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is the [portable filename character set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276) plus the addition to not start with a dash (minus) which makes sense as `-<attribute-name>` does unset it. It is also a nice property when compared with the extra checks on names with the [GNU `pathchk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/pathchk-invocation.html#pathchk-invocation) utility (cf. _"‘-P’"_). Thanks for the answer and the extra note on the consequences not using characters from the set.

Comment: And do you know by chance which locale applies to the character class `[-A-Za-z0-9_.]` you have in the answer?

Comment: I've made a reference to the function and file.  A line number would not be a good reference, since it would change as the file is edited.  The locale in question is ASCII, since the comparison is on byte sequences and doesn't involve an actual regular expression.

Comment: Well with a git revision this should be transparent, but thanks a lot first of all, that edit should already do it. And muchas gracias about the remark on ASCII. https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes is the best online refence I could find for `gitattributes(5)` so leaving it here, online. Thanks again for this good reference! And for the code I've taken a snapshot at archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20230607215605/https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/attr.c#n183